# friendly_id gem doesn't create slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, friendly-id

```
gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.4"
```

Model:

```
class Topic < Activerecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :generated_slug, use: [:slugged, :history]

  def generated_slug
    title
  end
end
```

On save of the topic from the new action, the slug doesn't get created and on top of that, the URL goes to something like this: http://localhost:3000/topics/7     and the browser gives this: undefined method `friendly' for #

**In addition, when I do this in the console:**

```
Topic.create! title: "Joe Schmoe"
```

the slug column becomes nil.

Comment: `class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
end`

User.create! title: "Joe Schmoe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another model with the same name overriding the friendly id behavior.